# How to place a view under two views?

Tags: eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

In case of using standard method

```
layout.addView(NewsView.ID, IPageLayout.BOTTOM, 0.7f, ChartView.ID);
```

`NewsView` will be placed under the `ChartView`.

[image: view under one view]

But how to specify that one view should be placed under two views?

[image: view under two views]

Comment: @greg-449 Thank you for the answer. I noticed that the folder "bottom" are added before the folder "right" in the cited code snippet. I changed the call order of addView() methods in my code, and got the needed result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this directly, you have to use separate IFolderLayouts to contain the views at the bottom, left and right.

For example:

```
IFolderLayout bottom = layout.createFolder("bottom", IPageLayout.BOTTOM, 0.7f, IPageLayout.ID_EDITOR_AREA);
bottom.addView("bottom.view");

IFolderLayout left = layout.createFolder("left", IPageLayout.LEFT, 0.25f, IPageLayout.ID_EDITOR_AREA);
left.addView("left.view");

IFolderLayout right = layout.createFolder("right", IPageLayout.RIGHT, 0.7f, IPageLayout.ID_EDITOR_AREA);
right.addView("right.view");
```

Here creating the bottom folder layout first makes it span the whole window.

Answer (score 0):

The order of add views is important and influence on the final layout.

This code will locate `NewsView` under the `ChartView` and `TransactionsView`:

```
layout.addView(ChartView.ID, IPageLayout.RIGHT, 0.2f, InstrumentsView.ID);
layout.addView(NewsView.ID, IPageLayout.BOTTOM, 0.6f, ChartView.ID);    
layout.addView(TransactionsView.ID, IPageLayout.RIGHT, 0.7f, ChartView.ID);
```

And this code will locate `NewsView` only under the `ChartView`:

```
layout.addView(ChartView.ID, IPageLayout.RIGHT, 0.2f, InstrumentsView.ID);
layout.addView(TransactionsView.ID, IPageLayout.RIGHT, 0.7f, ChartView.ID);
layout.addView(NewsView.ID, IPageLayout.BOTTOM, 0.6f, ChartView.ID);
```